# JavaScript Sleep Function

Tags: javascript, mootools, sleep

I have a banner rotator that refreshes every 60 seconds however I would also like each banner to be displayed for 20 seconds as there are 3 of them. I know where to put the setInterval code as indicated by my comment but I can't seem to get it to work. Any help or suggestions are very much appreciated.

```
var banners1 = {
    0:
    {
        'href': 'http://www.example.com/banner1.html',
        'src': 'http://www.example.com/banner1.gif'
    },
    1:
    {
        'href': 'http://www.example.com/banner2.html',
        'src': 'http://www.example.com/banner2.gif'
    },
    2:
    {
        'href': 'http://www.example.com/banner3.html',
        'src': 'http://www.example.com/banner3.gif'
    }

}
window.addEvent('domready', function() {
        function banner1()
        {
            var banner = $('banner1');
            var banner1Link = $('banner1').getElement('a');
            var banner1Image = $('banner1').getElement('img');

            for (var keys in banners1) {
                var object = banners1[keys];
                for (var property in object) {
                    if (property == 'href') {
                        var href = object[property];
                    }
                    if (property == 'src') {
                        var src = object[property];
                    }
                }
                banner1Link.setProperty('href', href);
                banner1Image.setProperty('src', src);
                console.log(href);
                console.log(src);
                /** wait 20 seconds **/
            }
        }
        var periodical = banner1.periodical(60000);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead:

```
    function banner1()
    {
        var banner = $('banner1');
        var banner1Link = $('banner1').getElement('a');
        var banner1Image = $('banner1').getElement('img');

        var delay = 0;
        for (var keys in banners1) {
            var func = (function(key) { return function() {
                var object = banners1[key];
                for (var property in object) {
                    if (property == 'href') {
                        var href = object[property];
                    }
                    if (property == 'src') {
                        var src = object[property];
                    }
                }
                banner1Link.setProperty('href', href);
                banner1Image.setProperty('src', src);
                console.log(href);
                console.log(src);
            }; })(keys);

            setTimeout(func, delay);
            delay += 20000;
        }
    }
```

JavaScript does not have a sleep-style function, because the document will not respond while JavaScript is running.  This means the user would not be able to interact with the page while the script is sleeping.

This approach schedules all three updates in one shot.  They will execute at 0 seconds (immediately), 20 seconds, and 40 seconds from the time the script runs.

Comment: If i am not mistaken this would cause a loop and never leave the first banner image.

Comment: @cdhowie. Seems like your suggestion puts the page into an endless loop at warp speed. ;)

Comment: @Nobody: Then you are implementing it incorrectly... can you use a debugger and analyze the loop and determine how it's happening?  (Recursion?  If so, which line re-enters the same function?  Infinite loop?  If so, which line opens the loop that's not terminating?)

Comment: @cdhowie. How can I be implementing it incorrectly when I copied and pasted your banner1 function code over mine?

Comment: @cdhowie: It seems to only want to display the first banner.

Comment: @Nobody: Gah, that's what I get for not testing and missing a stupid typo on my part, apologies.  I have fixed my code by replacing `setInterval` with `setTimeout`.  For some reason I always mix those functions up.  :(  The updated version has been tested and works over here.

Comment: @cdhowie: It works perfectly. Thank you for your prompt reply.

Answer (score 0):

you could use the javascript timeout

```
 setTimeout('', 20000);
```

This would be added right after the 20 sec comment. The first variable is any code/function you want called. and the second is the amount of time required before it is called in milliseconds (20 secs).

---

### EDITED ANSWER

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    var imgs1 = new Array("http://www.omniadiamond.com/images/jwplayer/enel_culture.png","http://www.omniadiamond.com/images/jwplayer/evas_srm.png","http://www.omniadiamond.com/images/jwplayer/jackolantern.png");
    var lnks1 = new Array("http://test.com","http://test.com","http://test.com");
    var alt1 = new Array("test","test","test");
    var currentAd1 = 0;
    var imgCt1 = 3;
    function cycle1() {
      if (currentAd1 == imgCt1) {
        currentAd1 = 0;
      }
    var banner1 = document.getElementById('adBanner1');
    var link1 = document.getElementById('adLink1');
      banner1.src=imgs1[currentAd1]
      banner1.alt=alt1[currentAd1]
      document.getElementById('adLink1').href=lnks1[currentAd1]
      currentAd1++;
    }
      window.setInterval("cycle1()",20000);
    </script>
    <a href="http://test.com" id="adLink1" target="_top">
    <img src="http://www.omniadiamond.com/images/jwplayer/enel_culture.png" id="adBanner1" border="0"></a>
```

This does cycle through all three in 60 secs at a 20 sec interval. and can be viewed at http://jsfiddle.net/jawilliams346614/wAKGp/ (it is set to a 1 sec interval)

Comment: Don't use strings with `setTimeout()`.  Use anonymous functions.

Comment: the setTimeout code above seems to want to iterate until it finds the end and will only show the last banner.

Comment: if you create a function, EX:function test() { return 0; }. and put the timeout to: setTimeout(test(), 20000); it will wait 20 secs then call it and see a value returned or a function that really does nothing and then continue through the for loop.

Comment: No it won't.  It will execute `test` immediately, and then attempt to execute its return value after 20000 seconds.